# Canonical equations (PDE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, canonical-transformation

Consider the equation
$$u_{xx} +2ay u_{xy} +e^{2x}
u_{yy} −u = 0,$$
where $a$ is a real constant. Determine the value(s) of a when this equation is elliptic everywhere in the $xy$-plane in which case find the canonical variables and reduce the equation to its canonical form. Explain where the canonical equation degenerates.

I just can't seem to find the canonical variables for this equation.

Comment: Elliptic implies that, for the PDE $$Au_{xx} + 2Bu_{xy} + Cu_{yy} + \dots = 0$$ we have $$B^{2} - 4AC < 0$$ Here, you have $B^{2} - 4AC = a^{2}y^{2} - 4e^{2x}$. Can you find value of $a$ now such that that this is less than zero for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I got that but it was getting the canonical variables I had trouble with  since my $a$ wasn't a constant but instead just an inequality $\lvert a\lvert < \lvert \frac{e^{2x}}{y}\lvert$

Comment: Considering that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, e^{2x} \ge 0 \implies -e^{2x} < 0$, so $a = 0$ is a value that yields the desired ellipticity $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Just as a side note, I made an error in my previous comment; you actually require $$B^{2} - AC < 0$$

Comment: Are you the same user from [this exact same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782313/reduce-the-equation-to-canonical-form-u-xx2ayu-xye2xu-yy-u-0/2782496#2782496)? See my answer there also